# Can SQL Server 2008 allow you to backup to a Mapped Network Drive?

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008, network-share

My SQL Server 2008 R2 has a mapped network drive (called `Y:/`) which reconnects after a reboot (I just checked this).

When I try to backup a Database (`TASKS -> BACKUP`). The network drive `Y:` is not listed as a possible destination. When I try to define the `Backup TO: Disk destination` location.

Can someone suggest why this is? What other solutions might I have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a UNC to the directory to which you want to backup. ex:  `\\servername\share`

Since mapped drives are only created on an interactive logon, if you schedule a backup to a mapped drive, the service account will not have access to it and fail. I can only presume this is why Microsoft excludes them from this dialog.

Comment: A very common problem with server processes and networked drives, permissions.  Comes up more often when people are trying to setup FTP servers to some NAS, same issue though.

Comment: AHHH - good point. What about iSCSI?

Comment: backups work great using the UNC path - I've had it running like a champ in the past. It's a PITA to get it working, but it does work.

Comment: iSCSI LUNs (aka drive letters) do not depend on interactive logons and are available when the system is booted, before anyone logs in.

Comment: am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)" error when I try the UNC path. What am i supposed to do to rectify this. The computers are not on a domain.

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD use UNC path when possible, but if you need to authenticate with different credentials (You still don't need to assign a drive letter though) or maybe use some third party network share that does not use UNC paths, you can use [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) to issue NET USE commands or whatever the third party share uses. Then the share will be available to the SQL Server process.

Be aware that xp_cmdshell is commonly frowned upon in security audits and the like.